# PHP - INSERT and save LAST_INSERT_ID() into a variable

Tags: php, mysql, return-value, mysqli-multi-query, last-insert-id

I'm sorry about my PHP skills, but I'm just not figuring out how to do this simple task which is INSERT a new row and save its ID into a variable.
Here's what I got:

```
    // mysql inserting a new row
$sql = "INSERT INTO `order` (orderTitle, orderDescription, orderPrice,userID, categoryID)
  VALUES('$title', '$description','$price','$userID','$category');";

$sql .= "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";
$result = mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql);

$result_get_id= mysqli_next_result($con);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result_get_id);
$order_id = $row[0]; // <-- how to get this value??
```

I realized row[0] doesn't work, which is why I would like to know how to extract the LAST_INSERT_ID() value correctly.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `mysqli_insert_id()`?

Comment: I've never seen any code that justified using `mysqli_multi_query()`. IMHO, it just makes things confusing. Your question is no different.

Comment: You should also use a prepared query instead of substituting variables into the SQL. Maybe the `INSERT` is getting an error.

Comment: @Barmar I wasn't using mysqli_insert_id() because I didn't know about it, but that seems to have done the trick, so thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things here...

1. Don't use `mysqli_multi_query` - it's unnecessary in your example. Use `mysqli_query` on the `INSERT` only. No need to query last insert id in SQL.
2. To get the last insert id, call `mysqli_insert_id` directly after your `INSERT` query. You can assign this to a variable, such as `$order_id = mysqli_insert_id();`

Answer (score 0):

The database class you're using has built in functions for this e.g. mysqli_insert_id(), or for PDO $db->lastInsertId().

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO order ... ");
printf ("Primary key of new record: %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php